# Get CloudBlockBlob metadata key not present in dictionary

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to create a list of VideoBlob objects (title, description, path) from metadata of a public blob in my storage account. The problem is that when I try to have a variable equal the blob's metadata ("title" is in the blob's metadata), I get

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

I've also tried adding in

```
blob.FetchAttributes();
```

but that gives me a 404 error. Any suggestions on how I can get the metadata?

Here's what the code looks like so far:

```
 static void iterateThroughContainer(CloudBlobContainer container)
        {
            List<VideoBlob> blobs = new List<VideoBlob>();

            VideoBlob video;

            CloudBlockBlob blob;

            String tagsString;

            foreach (IListBlobItem item in container.ListBlobs(null, true))
            {
                if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
                {
                    video = new VideoBlob();
                    blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(item.Uri.ToString());
                    video.uri = "test";
                    Console.WriteLine(blob.Metadata["title"]);
                    video.title = blob.Metadata["title"];
                    video.description = blob.Metadata["description"];
                    video.path = blob.Metadata["path"];
                    blobs.Add(video);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You must call FetchAttributes for the metadata to be populated.  If FetchAttributes is returning a 404 then it means you are trying to access a blob that doesn't exist.  You don't have your FetchAttributes code in the question so it is hard to see what you might be doing wrong, but that is where you should start.  Fiddler would be a good way to make sure that you are trying to get the attributes of the blob that you think you are accessing.

Comment: I just found that out as well that the blob didn't exist! Do you know of any good ways to get the name of the blob (in GetBlockBlobReference)?

Comment: Never mind, going to parse the URI. Thanks, kwill!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to call FetchAttributes, but you should pass [BlobListingDetails](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.bloblistingdetails.aspx).Metadata in to ListBlobs to specify metadata should be included when listing.

And you can simply cast **item** to a CloudBlockBlob object instead of calling GetBlockBlobReference.

Comment: This is perfect, Serdar! Made the changes and it worked just as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was passing in the wrong argument! I added a new method and fixed the GetBlockBlobReference parameter:

```
  foreach (IListBlobItem item in container.ListBlobs(null, true, BlobListingDetails.Metadata))
        {
            if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
            {
                video = new VideoBlob();
                blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(getBlobName(item.Uri.ToString()));
                video.uri = item.Uri.ToString();
                video.title = blob.Metadata["title"];
                video.description = blob.Metadata["description"];
             }
        }

 private String getBlobName(String link)
        {
             //convert string to URI
             Uri uri = new Uri(link);
             //parse URI to get just the file name
             return System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);  
        }
```